# Manipulate DOM of LWC using jQuery

Tags: jquery, lightning-web-components, shadow-dom

I know I cannot do:

```
var elements = this.template.querySelectorAll('[id^="fieldName"]')[0];
elements[0].getElementsByTagName('lightning-formatted-text')[0].setAttribute("style:", "myCSSAttribute:myCSSValue");
```

Does this mean then, that, I would also not be able to do something like

```
var elements = this.template.querySelectorAll('[id^="fieldName"]')[0];

elements.$(lightning-formatted-text')[0].setAttribute("style:", "styleattribute:value");
```

If that makes sense? I've been trying to see if I'm doing this syntactically wrong or if there is another way to achieve the same result??

Here is my template markup

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName}>
        <template for:each={fieldsArray} for:item='field'>
            <p key={field.index}><lightning-output-field id={field} field-name={field}></lightning-output-field></p>
        </template>
    </lightning-record-view-form>
    {dataStyleRulesList}
    <div id="testid" class="testid">testidcontent</div>
</template>
```

And, I've loaded Jquery as a module like so:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import getDataStyleRules from '@salesforce/apex/CustomMetaDataService.getDataStyleRulesForFields';
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
```

...

callAfterRenderAll() {
$("#testid").attr("style", "background-color:green");$("#testid").attr("style", "background-color:green");
}

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to, you should be able to achieve everything without using JQuery

Comment: Perhaps, I get a list of fields with the styles to be applied like so: {"data":{"fieldName__c":["color: black"],"otherFieldName__c":["color: blue"]}} but I can't think how I can , apply this style. such that the text of the output-field only is changed. I also can't really seen to say for each fieldName in data, this is the out[ut-field name, and the style=field's style list.

Comment: ok, so by marking my question as duplicate, we are saying, there is no way to change the inner html of this lightning-output-field text programmatically?

Comment: And if not, with the record-view-form, would it be possible to build a custom component to display lightning-output-fields individually and then edit their DOM to change the lightning-output_outputfield text-color ? because that is all i really, want to do.